# How to assign a Lead/Manager to an Employee in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in django and trying to create a web application like Employee Management System. I am trying to assign a lead to every employee.

I have been trying to find this Employee Manager relationship to get my requirement done for a long time.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False)
    empid = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Project(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def employee_details(request, id=None):
    context = {}
    context['user'] = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    return render(request, 'employee/details.html', context)

@login_required(login_url="/login/") @admin_only def employee_edit(request, id=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=user)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('employee_list'))
        else:
            return render(request, 'employee/edit.html', {"user_form": user_form})
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
        return render(request, 'employee/edit.html', {"user_form": user_form})
```

edit.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table table-bordered table-light">
        {{user_form.as_table}}
    </table>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning float-right">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}
<br>
    <table class="table table-light table-bordered table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Email Id</th>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <td>{{user.profile.empID}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <td>{{user.profile.designation}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Reporting to</th>
            <td>{{user.profile.Manager}}</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- <tr>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <td>{{user.profile.designation}}</td>
        </tr> -->
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="{%  url 'employee_edit' user.id %}">Edit</a>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I am able to select a Manager(who is also an employee) for an employee while adding a new employee. However, after saving the employee, Manager is not showing up in the details page. What could be the reason why I am not getting the manager listed for the employees? Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: Please share the view function and template for the page which isn't displaying correctly. The `ForeignKey` field looks fine in the model, the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: please edit this into your original question, with proper code formatting

Comment: Your model fields naming is not consistent, you should use lowercase separated by underscores. Check the django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

Comment: Added @RobinZigmond. Please let me know what I am missing here. Is there any default function or module for this use case?

Comment: I hope it is okay now @gdef_

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
{{user.profile.Manager}}
```

to

```
{{user.profile.manager.user.last_name}}
```

`manager` contains FK link to `self` model which is `Profile` which does not have `last_name` or something like that. `Profile` is linked to `User`.

Comment: Please describe what does "not working" mean. Do you have that data at all? What is stored in the model after save? Is there manager_id value assigned?

Comment: Thank you for helping me.. @Ivan Starostin. As I mentioned earlier, I can create an  employee where I can see manager field and I can select existing employee as a manager. After saving, it is not showing the manager name in employee details. I hope it answers your question.

Comment: I'm afraid it does not. Get your saved Profile like `p = Profile.objects.get(...)` and do `print(vars(p))`. What is stored in manager_id field? None?

Comment: Yes, you are right @Ivan Starostin. manager_id field shows None like this `'manager_id': None`

Comment: So there is nothing to show in detail page. Review your save/editing code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191028/discussion-between-senthamilvm-and-ivan-starostin).

Comment: I am still trying to get this fixed. Any other workarounds would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try printing all the values and instances for debug purpose in the view. Check what is stored in each field of the `user` instance. May be your assumption of it's type is wrong. Or the manager field is never being saved at all and is always empty.